# Laravel HasMany Relationships Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have 2 Tables proposals & Proposal Attachments. each proposal has a docx file & Pdf File. let me know the below table design is correct

proposals & proposal_attachments

---

```
    | id | proposalNo | ProposalTitle | Status |
    --------------------------------------------
    | 1  |  PRO 123  | sample         | 0      |
    --------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | proposal_id | version_ID |  Status  |    fileName    | filetype   | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |        1   | 1          |     1    |  Sample1.docx  | doctype   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2  |        1   | 1          |     1    |  Sample1.pdf   |   pdf     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  3  |        1   | 2          |     1    |  Sample2.docx  | doctype   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------  
|  4  |        1   | 2          |     1    |  Sample2.pdf   | pdf       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Should use like

```
|id| proposal_id|version_ID |Status|filetitle|fileNamedoc|fileNamePDF
```

Comment: | id | proposal_id | version_ID |  Status  |    filetitle    | fileNamedoc | fileNamePDF

Comment: My usage is if the docx has a PDF version show that. otherwise generate PDF.

Comment: my usage is on upload docx .. automatically docx convert into PDF file & store files. after in show blade. based on proposal ID and Version ID- PDf version. here using cloud convert API for Converting PDF,

Comment: We don't really know your requirements so this is something you're going to have to decide on.  Is there possibility for future doc types?    Is there possibility for more than one of the same type?

Comment: the proposal uploaded version in docx, ppt ,PDF .. but the generated version only in PDF